# I'm missing something

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

```
declare @servername varchar(2000)
set @EmriServerit=(select @@servername)
declare @dbname varchar(2000)
set @dbname ='Test1'
declare @Dir varchar(2000)
set @Dir='F:\dataclient.sql'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'osql -E -S ' + @servername+ ' -d ' + 
    @dbname +' -i ' + @Dir
```

It gives me  and error:
"incorrect sysntax near +"

If i don't use variables it works ok.
What am i missing!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be the missing space after servername?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additions are not allowed in a parameter list.  Move them to a separate line, like:

```
declare @cmd varchar(500)
set @cmd = 'osql -E -S ' + @servername+ ' -d ' + @dbname +' -i ' + @Dir
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign a value to `@servername`

Comment: I'm sorry i wrote it wrong on the post!
It is declare as servername

Answer (score 2):

I would try to concatenate together your command string first, and then check it before executing:

```
declare @servername varchar(2000)
set @servername = select @@servername

declare @dbname varchar(2000)
set @dbname ='Test1'

declare @Dir varchar(2000)
set @Dir='F:\dataclient.sql'

declare @execCmd varchar(max)
set @execCmd = 'osql -E -S ' + @servername+ ' -d ' + @dbname +' -i ' + @Dir

print @execCmd  -- what do you get as output here??

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @execCmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the entire `exec` on one line (this is a bit of a stab in the dark, I confess).

Comment: That's my fault... I made a line break when I reformtted the code.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
declare @EmriServerit varchar(2000)
set @EmriServerit=(select @@servername)
declare @dbname varchar(2000)
set @dbname ='Test1'
declare @Dir varchar(2000)
set @Dir='F:\dataclient.sql'
declare @Command varchar(500)

set @command='osql -E -S ' + @EmriServerit+ ' -d ' + 
    @dbname +' -i ' + @Dir
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @command
```

you had the server name declared and used differently, and you are not permitted to have expressions as parameters to a stored procedure, so concatenate the command into a variable and then pass it to the master.dbo.xp_cmdshell stored procedure.